# How to move an object from one array to another by condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, javascript-objects

Help me fix my code so that it works the way I would like.

I have an array of arrays (containers), containers already sorted by max weight per container 3300.

Condition:
Need to start from array C and move an object from container B to container C, if container C has a free space and an object from container B has the same container stage like as objects inside container C - transfer it. And repeat it for containers B, transfer an objects from containers A by the same condition. For example:

```
const first = [[{serial: '1', weight: 300, stage: 2}], [{serial: '2', weight: 3000, stage: 4}]]
const second = [[{serial: '3', weight: 300, stage: 1}], [{serial: '4', weight: 3000, stage: 2}],  [{serial: '5', weight: 2700, stage: 3}]]
```

```
// result
// updatedFirst: [[], [{serial: '2', weight: 3000, stage: 4}]]
// updatedSecond: [[{serial: '3', weight: 300, stage: 1}], [{serial: '1', weight: 300, stage: 2}, {serial: '4', weight: 3000, stage: 2}],  [{serial: '5', weight: 2700, stage: 3}]]
```

I transfer `first[0]` element to the `second[1]` because `second[1]` has a free space and has the same container stage.

I manage to transfer but not as I would like, there is a lot of free space after I transferred the objects. If for example in container B there is 1000 free space, and in container A there are 2 objects with a weight of 500 and 1000, my code will transfer an object with a weight of 500 but I want the object weighing 1000 to be transferred. Help solve the problem.

```js
const a = [[{serial: 'a1', weight: 2100.7, stage: 1}, {serial: 'a2', weight: 946.22, stage: 2}], [{serial: 'a3', weight: 1500, stage: 3}, {serial: 'a4', weight: 990, stage: 3}, {serial: 'a5', weight: 399.1, stage: 4} ]]
const b = [[{serial: 'b1', weight: 1999.7, stage: 1}, {serial: 'b2', weight: 1199.22, stage: 2}], [{serial: 'b3', weight: 10.2, stage: 3}, {serial: 'b4', weight: 599.1, stage: 4}]]
const c = [[{serial: 'c1', weight: 1000, stage: 1}, {serial: 'c2', weight: 59.22, stage: 2}], [{serial: 'c3', weight: 0.2, stage: 3}, {serial: 'c4', weight: 3099.1, stage: 4}]]

const updatedC = [...c]
const updatedB = [...b]

const updateContainers = (arr, from, to) => {
  let index = 0;
  let counter = 0;
  const total = {};

  arr.forEach((container, i) => {
    counter = 0;
    container.forEach(el => {
      const weight = +(counter += el.weight).toFixed(2);
      total[i] = weight;
    });
  });

  Object.keys(total).map((key, i) => {
    let freeSpace = 3300 - total[key];

    if (freeSpace > 0) {
      const stages = arr[i].map(el => el.stage);
      const containerStages = {
        min: Math.min(...stages),
        max: Math.max(...stages)
      };

      from.forEach((cont) => {
        cont.forEach((item, idx) => {
          if ((+item.stage >= containerStages.min && +item.stage <= containerStages.max) && +item.stage <= freeSpace) {
            to[i].push(item)
            freeSpace -= item.stage
            from.forEach((elem, elemI) => {
              elem.forEach((value, valueI) => {
                if (value.serial === item.serial) from[elemI].splice([valueI], 1)
              })
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  });
};

updateContainers(c, b, updatedC)
updateContainers(b, a, updatedB)

console.log(updatedC)
console.log(updatedB)
console.log(a)
```

````
// My result:
// a[0] free space: 1199.3 a[1] free space: 810
// b[0] free space: 1154.56 - not good; b[1] free space: 2341.8 - not good
// c[0] free space: 241.08 - good; c[1] free space: 190.5 - good


// Expected Result
// a[0] free space: 2353.7; a[1] free space: 2900.9
// a [[ {serial: 'a2', weight: 946.22, stage: 2}], [{serial: 'a5', weight: 399.1, stage: 4} ]]

// b[0] free space: 0.07 - good; b[1] free space: 210.9 - good
// b [[{serial: 'a1', weight: 2100.7, stage: 1}, {serial: 'b2', weight: 1199.22, stage: 2}], [{serial: 'a3', weight: 1500, stage: 3}, {serial: 'a4',weight: 990, stage: 3}, {serial: 'b4', weight: 599.1, stage: 4}]]

// c[0] free space: 241.09 - good; c[1] free space: 190.5 - good
// c [[{serial: 'b1',weight: 1999.7, stage: 1}, {serial: 'c1', weight: 1000, stage: 1}, {serial: 'c2', weight: 59.22, stage: 2}], [{serial: 'c3', weight: 0.2, stage: 3},{serial: 'b3', weight: 10.2, stage: 3}, {serial: 'c4', weight: 3099.1, stage: 4}]]```
````

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by saying "has a free space" , what is that free space? Empy array in container array?

Comment: @Arturas max weight per container is 3300
for example I have a two containers in an array:

`[
  [
    {serial: 'a2', weight: 946.22, stage: 2}
  ], 
  [
    {serial: 'a3', weight: 1946.22, stage: 3}, 
    {serial: 'a4', weight: 246.22, stage: 3}
  ]
]`

first container has a free space: 3300 - 946.22 = 2353.77;
second container has a free space: 3300 - (1946.22 + 246.22) = 1107.56